# jqTransform disappears in radajax after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, jqtransform

I have two dropdowns in a RadAjax panel. On SelectedIndexChanged of the first dropdown, the second one is populated.

After the initial page load the jqTransform is just fine. But after the postback it dissapears. I tried setting the property of the RadAjax ClientEvents-OnResponseEnd="setJqTransformFunc();" with no luck. Also i tried setting ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...,"setJqTransformFunc();"...) in code-behind in the event handler but with no luck also.

What confuses me the most is that, after the postback, i try to set the jqTransfrom manually from the Google Chrome's console, but it wouldt work that way as well.

Any ideas on how to preserve the jqTransform inside the RadAjax panel after postback?

PS: setJqTransformFunc() {$("form .myClass").jqTransform();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i did was, after the response i first remove the 'jqtransformdone' class first and re-apply the jqtransformation

$("form .myClass").removeClass('jqtransformdone').jqTransform();

this helped

Answer (score 0):

Give ResponseScripts a try:

```
RadAjaxPanel1.ResponseScripts.Add("setJqTransformFunc();");
```

Comment: How about using the format for OnResponseEnd that uses sender, eventArgs and then calling your setJqTransformFunc();?  http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-onresponseend.html

Comment: didnt work. its strange, i tried with jQuery datePicker and i have no problems on postbacks after i make the call to datePicker()...